# How I'm I going to use WorkManager if it needs other things?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I need to do some work and `WorkManager` seemed to be appropriate. However that work needs a reference to `Repository` which in turns uses `Retrofit` to obtain data and `Dao` to insert. `WorkManager` can run when the app is dead and therefore I won't have those objects flying around. How I'm I then supposed to do this?

Comment: Why can't you instantiate them when you need them?

Comment: @IvanWooll To instantiate `Repository` the constructor needs `Application`. Maybe I have to write it in a way that doesn't need that?

Comment: That's the right way to approach this I would agree. You may want to look into using Dagger and having an Application Component that can inject the application context wherever you need it.